# How to get a datetime object from a timestamp using the GMT delta in python?

Tags: android, python, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I'm currently collecting timestamp's using an android application which for some users stored the timezone as for example "GMT+03:00" browsing online I found this is not a proper timezone and because of that when trying to build a datetime object in python using

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
import pandas as pd
filename="data.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(filename)
[ datetime.fromtimestamp(data['timestamp'].iloc[i],
tz=tz.gettz(data['timezone'].iloc[i])) 
for i in range(data.shape[0]) ]
```

does not work well. For example using that datetime object as index to create a Pandas dataframe in order to use the rolling window feature does not work. Any idea how to transform the "GMT+03:00" into a proper timezone or some way to incorporate that information to build correctly a datetime object?

update: 
Here is a sample of `data['timestamps']`:

```
[1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719562.0, 1520719562.0]
```

and a sample of `data['timezone']`:

```
['GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00']
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for your `timestamp`?

Comment: Just updated with a sample

Answer (score 2):

GMT and UTC are the same.  You could do it *manually*: write a function to extract the offset and return a `datetime.timezone`.

```
import datetime, re
def get_tz(s):
    '''Returns a datetime.timezone object.

    Uses regular expression to extract the UTC offset from s.
    Assumes s is in the form of "GMT+03:00" or "GMT-03:00".
    Does NOT have exception handling.

    '''
    pattern = r'GMT([+-])(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})'
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    sign, hh, mm = match.groups()
    hh, mm = map(int, (hh, mm))
    t_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm)
    t_delta = t_delta * (1 if sign == '+' else -1)
    return datetime.timezone(t_delta)
```

Usage:

```
>>> timestamp = 1520719558.0
>>> timezone = 'GMT+03:00'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, get_tz(timezone))
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2018-03-11T01:05:58+03:00'
>>> timezone = 'GMT-03:00'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, get_tz(timezone))
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2018-03-10T19:05:58-03:00'
```

Comment: Beautiful use of regular expression ! Thanks !

Comment: enabled my answer !

Comment: when I run it I got
return datetime.timezone(t_delta)
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timezone'. Are you using python 3.+?

Comment: `timezone` is only available in python>3

Comment: Yes. this is Python version 3.6, datetime.timezone was new in v3.2.

Comment: If you cannot or do not want to use Python v 3.2: the source for the `datetime.timezone` class [is here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/datetime.py#L1949) . You could throw it into your *bag of tricks* and import it into your module.  Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt

# From wwii solution
def get_tz(s):
    '''Returns a datetime.timezone object.

    Uses regular expression to extract the UTC offset from s.
    Assumes s is in the form of "GMT+03:00" or "GMT-03:00".
    Does NOT have exception handling.

    '''
    pattern = r'GMT([+-])(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})'
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    sign, hh, mm = match.groups()
    hh, mm = map(int, (hh, mm))
    t_delta = dt.timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm)
    t_delta = t_delta * (1 if sign == '+' else -1)
    return dt.timezone(t_delta)

timestamps = [1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 1520719558.0, 
              1520719561.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719561.0, 1520719561.0,
              1520719562.0, 1520719562.0]
timezones = ['GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00',
             'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00',
             'GMT+03:00', 'GMT+03:00']
data = zip(timestamps, timezones)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=['timestamp', 'timezone'])

# Converts timezone to date object
data_df['timezone'] = data_df['timezone'].apply(lambda x:get_tz(x))

# Adding a new-column in the dataframe with the datetime format requested
data_df['date_time'] = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(row['timestamp'], row['timezone'])  
                        for (_, row) in data_df[['timestamp', 'timezone']].iterrows()
                      ]
```

Comment: Looking at your answer closer: OP's DataFrame has separate `timestamp` and `timezone` columns. Can you show how to combine them into a single Series that can be converted to datetime.datetime objects?

Comment: @wwii I just did. Thanks !